# Error reading file in C in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode6

I am trying to read a file in C in Xcode IDE, but every time a run the code it is getting stuck at a particular line and giving out **Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address = 0x68)** error. The code is given below

```
// Libraries to be included
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <math.h>

// Main function or entry point
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE * fp = fopen("~/Desktop/Primitivity/sample","r");
    int nCoeff, nFactors,answer, degree, i, temp;
    int check = 0;
    int * polynomial, *factors;

    // Error coming here
    check = fscanf(fp, "%d", &nCoeff);
}
```

It's prompting the error at the last line. I think that Xcode is unable to find the file. I tried absolute address and relative address. The file name is **sample** (no extensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need correction at 2 points

- Give fullpath to file in fopen. You need to expand "~".
- fopen will not understand "~".It will try to look for the file at absolute path starting with "~".
  Do a null check for fp. This will help you detect any problems in opening file. It can be file permissions issue also.

See the corrected code below.

```
FILE * fp = fopen("/Users/abc/Desktop/sample","r");
if(!fp)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to open file");
    return;
}
int nCoeff, nFactors,answer, degree, i, temp;
int check = 0;
int * polynomial, *factors;

check = fscanf(fp, "%d", &nCoeff);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, can you tell me how to give relative path in this environment. I just wrote "sample" instead of writing the entire address and kept the file in the local folder of the code.

Comment: Do you want to expand ~ to logged in user's home directory?

Comment: No, I want to give a relative address instead of an absolute address. For example the file "sample" is in the same directory as my code, I just want to write "sample" in fopen instead of "/Users/abc/Desktop/Primitive/sample"

Comment: You have to give the path relative to your executable, not the code. Assuming your final executable is at /Users/abc/Desktop, and "sample" file is at /Users/abc/Desktop/sample, the you can use the file name directly. If it is at /Users/abc/sample (one level up), the you can give "../sample". In Linux/OS X terminology, "." is current directory, ".." is parent directory. This link explains the concepts of "." and ".." http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/12f/notes/160_pathnames.html#dot-and-dot-dot-.-and-..

Answer (score 0):

It's occurring at the last line because `fp` is `NULL`. Try adding some error checking to the code, such as checking if `fp` is `NULL` and printing the value of `errno` and exiting the program if it is. See the `fopen(3)` and `errno(3)` man pages for more details.

(Also, it's the shell that expands "~", not the system call.)

Comment: fp is coming out to be NULL because it is not reading the file, this problem is only coming in Xcode, when I compile and run the program using gcc it is working.
I need to know how to make it read the file in Xcode.

Comment: Are you using any editor or you are compiling and running from terminal?